# Installing MAVROS package on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3, ros

I'm trying to install a ROS package (MAVROS) on my raspberry pi 3, but i can't find a way to do it. Other packages worked well, but this one starts aggravating me...

Specs:

- ROS Kinetic
- Rasbian

Can anyone help my with this?
Thanks!

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with c++. Second, there is not enough info in your question, read [ask] and revise it.

Answer (score -1):

First, add the ROS repository address to the source list.

**sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'**

and add public key to the ROS package.

**wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -**

and you need a update.
then, install ROS Kinetic.

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get upgrade**

**sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full**

for more info, visit this site.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials